# Hibernate updating records and implementing listeners : getting only required attribute values for event.getOldState()

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, rdbms, oop

I am using Hibernate 3 as my persistence framework.
Below is the sample hbm file I am using.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
     "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
     "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

    <hibernate-mapping>
      <class name="com.test.User" table="user">
      <meta attribute="implements">com.test.dao.interfaces.IEntity</meta>
      <id name="key" type="long" column="user_key">
            <generator class="increment" />
      </id>
     <property name="userName" column="user_name" not-null="true" type="string" />
     <property name="password" column="password" not-null="true" type="string" />
     <property name="firstName" column="first_name" not-null="true" type="string" />
    <property name="lastName" column="last_name" not-null="true" type="string" />
    <property name="createdDate" column="created_date" not-null="true" type="timestamp"     insert="false" update="false" />
   <property name="createdBy" column="created_by" not-null="true" type="string"  update="false" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I am added a post-update listener. What it will do is if there any updations perfomed on User then it will be invoked  and cahnges will be inserted to audit table.

Below is the sample implementation for postupdate event.

```
public void onPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent event)
{
LogHelper.info(logger, "Begin - onPostUpdate "
    + event.getEntity().getClass().getSimpleName());
if (!this.checkForAudit(event.getEntity().getClass().getSimpleName()))
{
 // check do we need to audit it.
}

// Get Attribute Names
String[] attrNames = event.getPersister().getEntityMetamodel()
    .getPropertyNames();
Object[] oldobjectValue = c
Object[] newObjectValue = event.getState();

this.auditDetailsEvent(attrNames, oldobjectValue, newObjectValue);
LogHelper.info(logger, "End - onPostUpdate");
// return false;
}
```

Here is my requirement.  event.getPersister().getEntityMetamodel()
        .getPropertyNames();  or event.getOldState();   or event.getState();

must return attribute names or value which i can update or insert.

Is there any way to control the return values of above one's.

Pleas help me on this regard.

Thanks,

Narendra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem Can be solved versy simply by using PostInsertEvent.getPersister().getPropertyInsertability();

It will return a boolean array . So by checking this array we can identify is it necessaty to insert them in audit table or not.

Answer (score 1):

> Here is my requirement. event.getPersister().getEntityMetamodel() .getPropertyNames(); or event.getOldState(); or event.getState();
>   must return attribute names or value which i can update or insert.

Not sure I understand... Do you want these specific methods to return a collection of attribute names and/or values, so that you use only these in a separate SQL insert/update clause into the Audit table? Are you inserting on that table on a per-attribute basis?

Also, have you read about Hibernate Envers? Envers is the Hibernate "extension" for auditing purposes: http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/index.html

Comment: Yes on attribute basis only I am adding them to audit table. I don't know about hibernate Envers.

Comment: What I mean is I must get only those attributes which can be insertable or updatable as defined in hbm file.